# get previous and next id in table of alphanumeric ids like 33, 33A, 44

Tags: mysql, alphanumeric

I have the following mysql table that lists scenes in a movie screenplay:

```
TABLE "scenes" 

id (AUTOINCR)    sceneId (VARCHAR)   
0                33
1                12
2                33A
3                44
```

As you see, the scenes are not sorted.

Now, I want to select a specific sceneId and figure out the scenes that come after and before.

I know how to sort the list in a "natural" way:

```
SELECT sceneId FROM scenes ORDER BY sceneId * 1 ASC
```

which gives me the sceneIds "12", "33", "33A", "44", which is the natural correct order.

Now, let's say I have the current sceneId "33", and want to figure out the id of the next sceneId, which is "33A" having id 2.

Searching for the next row in the list with > does not work, as it gives me 44 after 33, not 33A:

```
SELECT id, sceneId FROM scenes WHERE sceneId > 33 (or "33" as it is a varchar?).
```

How can I select these alphanumeric types?

thx, 
Matthias

Comment: What do you get when you run `SELECT id, sceneId FROM scenes WHERE sceneId > '33' order by sceneId * 1 ASC limit 1`

Comment: I build a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8d4a9/2/0

Comment: @Kinesias to get the previous, you have to sort DESC, but you have to always sort both for the numeric value and the string value

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with your first query, if you order just by:

```
ORDER BY sceneId * 1 ASC
```

both strings "33" and "33A" are converted to number 33, so if "33A" comes after "33" it's just a matter of luck, in this particular context it is better to order by:

```
ORDER BY sceneId * 1 ASC, sceneId ASC
```

so to get the next row in the list you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM scenes
WHERE
  sceneId>'33'
ORDER BY
  sceneId * 1 ASC, sceneId ASC
LIMIT 1
```

and to get the previous you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM scenes
WHERE
  sceneId<'33A'
ORDER BY
  sceneId * 1 DESC, sceneId DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the scenes for 33:

```
SELECT id, sceneId FROM scenes WHERE CAST(sceneId AS UNSIGNED)=33;
```

You could have performance gain by using indexes with the LIKE command and then CAST (in order to exclude "331" when you are searching for 33)

```
SELECT id, sceneId FROM scenes WHERE
   sceneId LIKE '33%'
   AND CAST(sceneId AS UNSIGNED)=33;
```

Get the next scene after 33, you have just to put some quotes around

```
SELECT id, sceneId FROM scenes WHERE sceneID>"33" ORDER BY sceneId LIMIT 1;
```